# generate sample(synthetic data ) in avro format based on avdl file using python

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, spark-avro, avro-tools, fastavro

I would like to generate synthetic data to test my pipelines.  is there a simple way to generate sample avro files for a given avdl file using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `fastavro` using the `generate_many` helper. There is an example in the docs: https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html#fastavro.utils.generate_many